# Is there any program that shows all hardware?

Tags: hardware

Is there any program that shows all hardware (e.g. Graphic card NVIDIA GeForce 9600GT, Network card, and so on) on your computer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of command line programs that give you this kind of information, you could try `lshw` and `lspci`.
For a GUI that nicely displays information from these and other sources, try [hardinfo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardinfo) [image: Install hardinfo].

[image]

It will appear in the applications menu under **System > System Profiler and Benchmarks**.
As the name suggests, it also offers some benchmarks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for `lspci`. It's not all hardware; but it is the ones you listed and it's usually the one I want.

(`lshw` also exists, although I'm not sure if it's installed by default. It's usually more info than I want)

Answer (score 1):

The old school method that I use is to type `dmesg` at the prompt.  It will show you the last startup log of the Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

[Find Hardware Specs (Details) on your Computer](http://embraceubuntu.com/2007/02/18/find-hardware-specs-details-on-your-computer/)

> I stumbled upon the nifty “lshw” tool today. lshw lists your hardware.
>   Try it now:
>
> ```
> sudo lshw
> ```
>
> You can get specific details by using the -C flag:
>
> ```
> sudo lshw -C disk
> ```
>
> will list all you hard disks.
>
> It can create a html page with your hardware details if you do:
>
> ```
> sudo lshw -html > your-file-name.html
> ```

Comment: The lshw GUI looks like this:  http://dailypackage.fedorabook.com/uploads/2008-02-28-lshw-gui.png